# Dynamic table in template written in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I try do build a dynamic table, this table should replace a fix table.

```html
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Aufgabe</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>Summe</th>
    <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td> </td>  

<td><input type="text" id="punkte0" name="punkte0" value="{$punkte.0}" size="3" onKeyUp="aktualisieren('punkte0','punkte1')" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="punkte1" name="punkte1" value="{$punkte.1}" size="3" onKeyUp="aktualisieren('punkte1','punkte2')" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="punkte2" name="punkte2" value="{$punkte.2}" size="3" onKeyUp="aktualisieren('punkte2','punkte3')" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="punkte3" name="punkte3" value="{$punkte.3}" size="3" onKeyUp="aktualisieren('punkte3','punkte4')" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="punkte4" name="punkte4" value="{$punkte.4}" size="3" onKeyUp="aktualisieren('punkte4','punkte5')" /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="punkte5" name="punkte5" value="{$punkte.5}" size="3" onKeyUp="aktualisieren('punkte5','punkte6')" /></td>

<td id="tds1">0</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gesamt</td>
<td colspan="6"></td>
<td id="summe">0</td>
<td id="note">{$student.note/10}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But the columns should be user-dependent, so I wrote a function in my PHP code, which save the value (number between 4 an 7) in my database. It is called in the database `klausuraufgaben`.

I tried this to replace the columns:

```html
$iQuantity = (integer)$_POST['klausuraufgaben'];
$aTableHeads = [];
$aTableContents = [];

for ( $x=0; $x<$iQuantity; $x++ ) {
$aTableHeads[] = '<th>' . ($x + 1) . '</th>';
$aTableContents[] = '<td><input type="text" id="punkte' . (string)$x . '" name="punkte' . (string)$x . '" value="{$punkte.' . (string)$x . '}" size="3" onKeyUp="aktualisieren('punkte. (string)$x . '",'punkte. (string)$x+1 . '"></td>';
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone see what is wrong?

This is the Error, which I get:

> [in kartei.tpl line 254]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: $aTableHeads[] = '' . ($x + 1) . ''; $aTableContents[] = '

Comment: Mmm, aren't you using twig or other template engine?

Comment: yes. i use smarty. the fix table function very well, but the php code not. is it a smarty problem?

Comment: So wouldn't the for loop in smarty work for you? https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.for.tpl

Comment: thanks, i edit the code for the template in this way                                       {php}
   $iQuantity = (integer)$_POST['klausur_aufgaben'];
   $aTableHeads = [];
   $aTableContents = [];
    
 {for $x=0 to $iQuantity;}
 //  {for( $x=0; $x<$iQuantity; $x++ )

    $aTableHeads[] = '<th>' . ($x + 1) . '</th>';
    $aTableContents[] = '<td><input type="text" id="punkte' . (string)$x . '" name="punkte' . (string)$x . '" value="{$punkte.' . (string)$x . '}" size="3" onKeyUp="aktualisieren('punkte. (string)$x . '",'punkte. (string)$x+1 . '"></td>'; 
    {/for}
{/php}

Answer (score 2):

thanks, i edit the code for the template in this way:

```html
{php}
   $iQuantity = (integer)$_POST['klausur_aufgaben'];
   $aTableHeads = [];
   $aTableContents = [];
    
{for $x=0 to $iQuantity;}
 //  {for( $x=0; $x<$iQuantity; $x++ )

$aTableHeads[] = '<th>' . ($x + 1) . '</th>';
$aTableContents[] = '<td><input type="text" id="punkte' . (string)$x . '" name="punkte' . (string)$x . '" value="{$punkte.' . (string)$x . '}" size="3" onKeyUp="aktualisieren('punkte. (string)$x . '",'punkte. (string)$x+1 . '"></td>'; 
    {/for}
{/php}
```

Comment: yes, but i still get error messages, what else is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps something like that answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not smarty expert, but lets have a crack at this.

```
{php}
   $iQuantity = (integer)$_POST['klausur_aufgaben'];
{/php}
   <tr> 
{for $x=0 to $iQuantity}
  <th>{$x + 1}</th>
{/for}
  </tr>

{for $x=0 to $iQuantity}
  <td><input type="text" id="punkte{$x}" name="punkte{$x}" value="NotSureHere this needs to come from another array?" size="3" onKeyUp="aktualisieren('punkte{$x}','punkte{$x+1}')"/></td>
{/for}
```

Comment: Just noticed I had an extra php tag, taken it off told you I wasn't an expert!

Comment: sorry, richard, but it wasn´t meant in this way, no matter what i did, i alway get smarty errors

Comment: Ok, sorry I can't help you more. I did see that we don't need the ';' at the end of the $iQuantity variable - I'll edit the answer. But unsure about this whole thing. I've never done smarty programming.